# animate angular list when push to object

Tags: angularjs, animation, ng-animate

Hi need your help with ng animate

i have this template of the directive :

```
<ul class="col-sm-10">
  <li  class="animate" ng-repeat="event in vm.dataList track by $index">
      <div class="active">
        <img class="overview" ng-src="{{event.data1}}">
        <div class="enterTime">{{event.data2}}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my directive is : (link function) - listen to change in data if there is change then need to add to the list

```
   scope.$watch('data', function(newIsOpenVal, oldIsOpenVal){
         var newobj = {};

         if(newIsOpenVal != oldIsOpenVal)
         {
           newobj = scope.eventData;
           newobj.buttonStatus =  scope.buttonStatus;
           console.log(newobj);
           ctrl.dataList.unshift(newobj);
         }

      });
```

1. - I m trying to add loader animation until the push is will finish 
     i have jquery code with animate()  but how and where I put it to show loader until the list will be update

     2. tried to use ng-animate for enter new list but this is not working
        with class="animate"  , module dependencies and css 
        it still show the item in list after pushing without animation

btw animation on simple button is working 

 
thx

Answer (score 0):

1. Include angular-animate[-min].js.
2. Make your module depend on ngAnimate.
3. Define your transitions in CSS using classes like .ng-enter and .ng-enter-active.
4. Use ng-repeat as you normally would.

   `.animate.ng-enter {
        -webkit-transition: 1s;
        transition: 1s;
        opacity: 0;
   }
   .animate.ng-enter-active {
       opacity: 1;
   }`